# How to call complete internal flows multiple times in Sequence Diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Main Idea: To convert an activity diagram into a sequence diagram.

Problem: I want that if "Action 2" fails then, in that case all the flows get triggered again from "Action 1".

(i.e Action 1 --> Action 2 --> then the verification again. and this should happen until Action 2 is Successful)

Basically, the flow works like a GOTO function and then from there triggers all the steps again.

I have tried to use a ref block but again it seems that it might be ambiguous and someone might read it only as the "execution of Action 1" and not the steps after it.

Therefore I wanted some hints to make this sort of scenario clear. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Attaching the image for better clarity of the problem.

[image]

Comment: You can use `loop` fragment like your `ALT`. But that will start you "graphical programming" which is just futile. You already documented that with the AD. There's no point in repeating that in a SD.

Comment: What is your primary intention to "convert" an AD into a SD?

Comment: The primary intent behind converting the AD into a SD is so that I can clearly identify and mention what action (that is mentioned in the AD) will be performed by what entity in my system and in what order.

Comment: In that case you should not stop! Add an Interaction diagram. And clearly one or two powerpoint slides will help too. If that's not clear. it's sarcasm. Redundancy has never helped anyone except adding futile extra work and leaving inconsitent duplicates. Use SDs for _complicated_ collaborations, not for repeating business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity and sequence diagrams are not supposed to be equivalent. Both set a different focus (flow vs interactions) and as a consequence you might have to do the mapping by identifying  higher-level constructs.

Here you have clearly a loop:

[image]

You could reformulate in pseudocode as: `REPEAT action 1 and action 2 UNTIL action 2 passes`, which is a loop that has the test in the end.  You could further rewrite this loop into: `Last did not passed; WHILE last did not pass, DO action 1 and action 2`, or `WHILE true DO action 1 and action 2 and BREAk if it succeeds`.

Now you can use a [loop fragment](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-loop) to achieve this behavior in a sequence diagram.  This fragment would enclose action1, action 2, and the test for success, and after the loop,  would come the interaction for the success case.   The nesting makes it very explicit what gets repeated and what not. For example, some variant of:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the hint. I will use the loop and break block approach to mention this kind or scenarios.

Comment: See my comments above...